# Clash between trailing return type and return type deduction

Tags: c++, function, return-type, auto, trailing-return-type

I'm writing some code where the return type of a function is rather complicated. I'd like to make use of `auto` for deducing from the return type, but that's obviously not possible in a forward declaration. So I was hoping to at least only duplicate the contents of the return statement and do the following,

```
int q = 5; // veeery complicated type

/* Declaration - the best we can do */
auto f() -> decltype(q);

/* Later, in a different file */    
auto f() {
  return q;
}
```

This produces the following error in GCC 7,

```
error: ambiguating new declaration of ‘auto f()’
note: old declaration ‘int f()’
```

Of course I could repeat

```
auto f() -> decltype(q) {
  return q;
}
```

in the definition (which works) but why should I need to when the return type is already uniquely given by the `return` statement? How is the type of `f` in my definition ultimately any more ambiguous than `int f()`?

Comment: Not a standard guru, but what is the compiler supposed to do if, according to your actual definition of the function, the trailing type and `auto` deduced type don't match? I think that's the reason why gcc report it.

Comment: I'd expect it to simply tell me it didn't match. Whether two types are the same or not should be easy to answer. But now that you mention this, quite interestingly the error produced by `int f(); long f() { return 1; }` is worded the same way!

Comment: I'd agree with you. I'd also like to know is there any standard reference that explicitly states that an `auto`-deduced return type can not be fold with a concrete return type function (even if they match).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem here is that a trailing return is not the same as purely deduced return type.  In [dcl.spec.auto]/2

> [...]If the function declarator includes a *trailing-return-type* (8.3.5), that specifies the declared return type of the function

So

```
auto f() -> decltype(q);
```

is really

```
int f();
```

which is different from

```
auto f()
```

There is also [dcl.spec.auto]/13

> Redeclarations or specializations of a function or function template with a declared return type that uses a placeholder type shall also use that placeholder, not a deduced type.  [ Example:
>
> ```
> auto f();
> auto f() { return 42; }  // return type is int
> auto f();                // OK
> int f();                 // error, cannot be overloaded with auto f()
> decltype(auto) f();      // error, auto and decltype(auto) don’t match
> ```

Which is kind of opposite of what is going on here but it does further exemplify that this is not allowed